# Re-installation requirement if a disk fails?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have 4 x 2TB hard drives in my 1U server, running on CentOS (for personal use). When I installed them, I selected everything to be in `/home` partition. My question is - what will happen if one of the disks fail? Do I need to re-install the whole server? What is the correct way to install a server with 4 disks so I don't have to re-install if some of the disks fails? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install with RAID?

Comment: @roaima I do not have a RAID configuration on my system but I can create one if needed. What is the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for RAID (Redundant Array of Independent Disks). There are many different configuration options depending on available hard drives, speed and redundancy requirements.

The basic principle of a RAID system is to distribute the data across different hard drives to increase reliability such that, in an event of a disk failure (or multiple simultaneously), the data can be restored without loss.

Some common raid forms:

- RAID-0: The data is spread across multiple hard drives. This improves performance, but if one disk fails all the data is gone.
- RAID-1: This mirrors the drives i.e it stores an exact copy on all drives. If one disk fails, the data remains unaffected.
- RAID-5: The data is spread across drives, but in a way so that the data can be recovered. This configuration allows up to one drive failure.
- RAID-6: Similar to RAID-5, RAID-6 allows for two simultaneous drive failures. It is also able to handle a disk failure while rebuilding data from a previous failure.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I commented I thought this question was about the login bypass, where you also commented. I'm actually familiar with RAID and I'll accept that answer, but I was curious is it possible to do it without RAID since I'm planning to use all of the 4 disks? I'm more concerned about the pre-installing and deleting the data of the other 3, than losing the data in the failed one. Thanks!

Comment: What stops you from using RAID on all 4 disks?

Comment: @user1686 I wanted to use all 8TB on that server. If I use RAID-1 I'm gonna use only 4TB. In my case I'll probably use RAID-5 so I can use 6TB of 8TB.

Comment: RAID 10 or RAID 5. But remember to take backups